# Sum up pivot as line difference in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, pivot-table, google-sheets-formula

I have a pivot with two columns, where i want to sum up values from both columns as the difference between value in column B and column C. Pivot display setting offers only an overall sum. How can i display values as % from the difference?

Pivot looks like:

```
+------------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+
| Search query                 | 2020-11-02 | 2020-11-09 | Summ|
+------------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+
| ambulante zusatzversicherung | 22,12      | 20,09      | 42,21       |
+------------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+
```

But i want to make it like:

```
+------------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+
| Search query                 | 2020-11-02 | 2020-11-09 | Diff|
+------------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+
| ambulante zusatzversicherung | 22,12      | 20,09      | =C2-B2       |
+------------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+
```

Is there such option? or how can i do this? In the pivot options i can't find an option `=MINUS(C2,B2)`

**PS**: Its evidently to do this with a formula, like i did. But i want to know, whether there is such pivot option i don't realized?

**PPS**: the data before pivoting looks like:

```
+------------------------------+------------+------------------+
| Search query                 | Week       | Average position |
+------------------------------+------------+------------------+
| ambulante zusatzversicherung | 2020-11-09 | 20,09            |
+------------------------------+------------+------------------+
| ambulante zusatzversicherung | 2020-11-02 | 22,12            |
+------------------------------+------------+------------------+
| autoversicherung             | 2020-11-09 | 28,66            |
+------------------------------+------------+------------------+
| autoversicherung             | 2020-11-02 | 29,85            |
+------------------------------+------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Can you post your original data before the pivot?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo sure, did it in the post. There are always only two weeks at all, for each search query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?
Formula in E3 is:

```
={      query({A3:C7},"select Col1,sum(Col3) group by Col1 pivot Col2",1),
  query(query({A3:C7},"select Col1,sum(Col3) group by Col1 pivot Col2",1),"select Col3-Col2 label Col3-Col2 'Diff'",1)}
```

If I have the Diff backwards, just change "Col3-Col2" to "Col2-Col3" in several places in the formula.

I've included the Diff column as part of the whole answer, but it could be a simpler formula, like `=arrayformula(G4:G-E4:E)` in H4 if you like.  And then the query just needs the first line basically.

Let us know if this doesn't solve your issue.

[image]

Comment: Very interesting solution